# code variables in template blogger does'nt work

Tags: css, variables, blogger

I Have That Code variables`/* Variable definitions
   ====================

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-HVN40_BkdS4/VMJsvSi2lqI/AAAAAAAAAEs/oVIzP8TKACk/s150-no/A.png) repeat scroll top left"/>

*/
`I Have Add them IN A Template Blogger After  But She Does'nt Work Please Help me.

Comment: what is your question??

Answer (score 0):

That is not a variable.
[here](http://bloggerillustrated.blogspot.ch/2012/07/how-to-add-support-for-blogger-template-designer-in-custom-templates.html) you can find out how a Blogger Variable is written.